# What is wrong with my procedural function to find all prime $\leq x$?

Tags: procedural-programming, prime-numbers

I want to create a simple function that prints all prime numbers from 1 to x. I have the following code, which doesn't cause any errors from the kernel but it doesn't return anything:

```
allprimes[x_] = For[i=0, i<=x, i++, If[PrimeQ[i], Print[i]]]
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try `allprimes[x_] := For[i=0, i<=x, i++, If[PrimeQ[i], Print[i]]]; allprimes[7]`

Comment: Yep: an issue with `Set` (`=`) vs `SetDelayed` (`:=`). See the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[allprimes]

allprimes[x_] = For[i = 0, i <= x, i++, If[PrimeQ[i], Print[i]]]
```

Look at the stored definition of `allprimes`

```
?allprimes
```

[image]

Since you use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) the RHS evaluated immediately and was equal to `Null`. Use [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
Clear[allprimes]

allprimes[x_] := For[i = 0, i <= x, i++, If[PrimeQ[i], Print[i]]]
```

The stored definition is then

```
?allprimes
```

[image]

```
allprimes[5]

(* 2

3

5 *)
```

However, a more flexible approach is

```
Clear[allprimes]

allprimes[x_] := Select[Range[0, x], PrimeQ]

allprimes[5]

(* {2, 3, 5} *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't think about the consequences of set vs set-delayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the functions [`Prime`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prime.html), [`PrimePi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimePi.html) and [`Range`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html):

```
ClearAll[primesLessThanOrEqualTo]
primesLessThanOrEqualTo[x_] := Prime[Range[PrimePi[x]]]
primesLessThanOrEqualTo[20]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}

A fancier way to define the same function as a pure function (composition of the three functions):

```
ClearAll[primesLessThanOrEqualTo2]
primesLessThanOrEqualTo2 = Prime@*Range@*PrimePi
primesLessThanOrEqualTo2[20]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}

You can also use a combination of [`NextPrime`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NextPrime.html) and [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[primesLessThanOrEqualTo3]
primesLessThanOrEqualTo3[x_] := Most@NestWhileList[NextPrime, 2, # <= x &]
primesLessThanOrEqualTo3[20]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}

**Note:** `primesLessThanOrEqualTo` and `primesLessThanOrEqualTo2` are much faster than `primesLessThanOrEqualTo3`.